# How to convert array of 0s and 1s to array of strings in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have the following python array: `np.array([1,1,1,0,0])` and I want to convert it to the following array: `np.array(['yes','yes','yes','no','no])` based on the condition `if 1, 'yes', else 'no'`. What's the best way to do this? I'm happy to do it either in place or in a separate array.

Comment: Can't be in-place.  The array has integer dtype.  It can't hold strings.

Comment: `np.array(["no","yes"])[<your_array>]`

Answer (score 2):

Use [np.where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([1,1,1,0,0])

result = np.where(arr, 'yes', 'no')
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
['yes' 'yes' 'yes' 'no' 'no']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use list comprehension:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([1,1,1,0,0])

result = np.array(['yes' if x else 'no' for x in arr])

print(result)
```

**Output:**
`['yes' 'yes' 'yes' 'no' 'no']`